# Transforming an existant VC++ project using ITK or OpenCV library to a DLL , is it possible?

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-c++, dll, itk

Is there any way to compile existant projects written in vc++ and libraries such as ITK or OpenCV into DLL files ? The purpose here is to call the functions implemented in these subprojects in a final software, using simple DLL files, instead of gathering tens of header and source files from different modules with DLLs and .lib files of the used libraries. So what are the steps I need to make to obtain the DLLs, and how should I interface the functions (the main functions also) of each subproject (module) in order to make them convenient for use in my final project ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make your existing project as  dll project by changing the target format. or create a fresh dll project.
2. add existing dll in your target folder and lib as dependent input file in linker section of propeties of project.

3.You want to bundle all your dlls and libs into single dll or lib then you have download source code of each dependent and add in single project and build it as your own dll.